# Автопрокрутка для слайдов при использовании fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как реализовать автопрокрутку горизонтальных слайдов, если я использую плагин fullPage.js?

Comment: Использовать [afterRender](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#afterrender) + [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), внутри которого будет интересующий Вас метод (moveSectionDown/moveSlideRight...).

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich Большое спасибо за ответ. Дело в том что я в javascript разбираюсь очень слабо. Не могли бы вы подробнее мне ответить по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью `setInterval` прокручивать слайд в нужном направлении, используя [afterRender()](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/#afterrender). Этот колбэк срабатывает, когда страница построена.

Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({   
        anchors: ['home', 'about', 'contact'],

        afterRender: function () {
            setInterval(function () {
                $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
            }, 2000); // каждые 2 секунды крутим вправо
        }
});
```

Пример в работе: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/th6cfw7o/)**